# jquery, position 'close icon' div in the top right of a large image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My webpage has a large image (a map).  I want to position, at the top right of the image, a small icon that is for closing the map.

How can I figure out the position and place the image appropriately?

The image has a fixed width of 900 x 600.

I have jquery on the page if that helps.

I tried using $("#map").position and I have the top and left, but not sure how to position to the top right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way would just to positon the close button absolutely with CSS instead of calculating the positon with JS. For example:

```
<div id="map" style="position: relative;">
  <img src="yourmap.png">
  <img src="close.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;">
</div>
```

Comment: problem is, the map js code wipes everything out inside of the id=map div.

Comment: So wrap your dynamic div in a wrapper, with the close image and use the above css.

Comment: Can't you add the close image in you map js code? (EDIT: Or what Bigfellahull said).

Comment: then try it with a wrapper around: `<div id="map_rapper style="position: relative;"><div id="map" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;"><img src="..."/></div><img src="close.png" style="position: absolute; top:0; right:0;"/></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at the latest [jQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/) bits. They have [some facilities](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) for positioning elements relative to other elements on the page.  Depending on what browsers your wanting to support this could be simpler than creating the browser-agnostic CSS.